# OpenSSH using private key on Windows ("Unprotected private key file" error)

Tags: key, openssh

I am attempting to do a simple connection to a SSH server using OpenSSH for Windows using a private key, and am met with this:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'private' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "private": bad permissions
```

On Linux, this is fixed with a simple chmod 600 on the private key file, however Windows does not have an equivalent method.

This sounds like something that should be pretty easy, but I am completely unable to find any reasonable solution to it. Is there a way to either add the private key directly without going through a file, or to skip this privacy check? Or am I missing something else entierly?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] instead of here.

Comment: 'On Linux, this is fixed with a simple chmod 600 on the private key file' this was exactly what I was searching for ;)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use `icacls` in Windows instead of `chmod` to adjust file permission. To give the current user read permission and remove everything else (Which will allow openssh to work), this works nicely:

Command Prompt:

```
icacls .\private.key /inheritance:r
icacls .\private.key /grant:r "%username%":"(R)"
```

In PowerShell, you can get `icacls` to work by wrapping the command in a call to `cmd.exe`

```
icacls .\private.key /inheritance:r
start-process "icacls.exe" -ArgumentList '.\private.key /grant:r "$env:USERNAME":"(R)"'
```

Comment: Also, username may need a domain prefix (e.g. if using cloud identities)

Comment: No, that is for cmd only. For powershell I would imagine it's something along the lines of $env:UserName instead of %username% (The " are still important as usernames might have spaces in them)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have put that in. `$env:USERNAME` is correct (though case doesn't actually matter). Still, the command won't work though since PowerShell doesn't like the cmd.exe style arguments, you would have to wrap the whole thing in a call to cmd.exe. I mention all this since PowerShell is now the default command shell for W10.

Comment: icacls seems a bit broken on powershell indeed. After a while of trial, error, and googling, it seems that wrapping it in a call to cmd.exe is the correct way to do it.

start-process 'icacls.exe' -ArgumentList '.\test /grant:r "$env:username":"(R)"'

Should work

Comment: Doesn't work for me, file is 0444 after running the above, so it's still world readable.

Comment: I dunno what to tell you. I just checked it and it still works as expected. Are you running the commands as the correct user? (aka: Not administrator)?

Comment: @PhilippeChaintreuil I think it has been caused by You had more users on your local machine. Windows by default gave them privileges to file. You have to iterate over all users and remove their rights.

Comment: @PiotrZych , that was exact issue. Thank you! Wonder why these things are not documented anywhere. The projects are executed in agile mode and these issues delay the sprint items and make us look incompetent :(

Comment: I love you, you saved my life

Comment: While running in Windows Terminal, I had to modify it a little bit as follows:-
```start-process "icacls.exe" -ArgumentList ".\key.pem /grant:r ""$env:USERNAME"":""(R)"""```

Comment: @NikhilAgarwal Yes, the filename will need to be renamed to match the name and type of the actual file you're using. private.key was simply the default filename for it 4 years ago :) You don't need to run start-process in terminal, but if you do, then you are again correct in having to use " instead of ', and having to encapsulate the entire sentence in an additional ", as terminal handles spaces very poorly

Answer (score 22):

FYI: Rename the "test.pem" to your original pem file name.

1. Setting path variable

   `$path = ".\test.pem"`
2. Reset to remove explicit permissions

   `icacls.exe $path /reset`
3. Give current user explicit read-permission

   `icacls.exe $path /GRANT:R "$($env:USERNAME):(R)"`
4. Disable inheritance and remove inherited permissions

   `icacls.exe $path /inheritance:r`

Note:

- You can replace the file name as per your file name. In this case it is test.pem.
- You must be in the same directory where your file is located.
- You must open power shell as administrator.

Comment: You save my droplet acces! Did it both for my file and file.pub, works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't knew `icalcs` was `chmod` equivanelt on Windows haha ! Thanks a ton ! Just wanted to add if you get permission denie error while file deletion, then again use command `icacls.exe $path /reset`.

Answer (score 5):

I did it on Windows 10 and it fixed the issue as you can see in the image as well.

You should change the owner of the file(which contains the private key)to your username with full access.
and then remove the other usernames that have access to that file.

1. right-click on the file which contains the private key and clicks on properties and then Security tab> Advanced
   by clicking on the **change** button you can change the owner to your username.
   (if you don't know the name of your username run: "**echo %USERNAME%**" in command prompt.)
   Change>Advanced...>Find Now
2. remove all Permission entries except the one you just added

click on Disable inheritance> Convert inherited permissions...
then remove all Permission entries except the one you just added.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlnMS.png)

Answer (score 5):

For windows 10
store the key file in User
Ex: C:\Users\MANNEM.ssh

Make sure permission of private key file will be as shown in the image
[image: permissions]

[image: permissions]

Answer (score 4):

You locate the file in Windows Explorer, right-click on it then select "Properties". Navigate to the "Security" tab and click "Advanced".

Change the owner to you, disable inheritance and delete all permissions. Then grant yourself "Full control" and save the permissions. Now SSH won't complain about file permission too open anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Save the following script and run it for the keys you need to reset the permission for.

This is based on the commands given in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70107180/107537)

```
# ResetKeyPermssions.ps1 <keyfile>
# Resets windows permissions for private key file, such that ssh-add doesn't complain about permissions being too open

$path = $args[0]
#icacls.exe $path /reset #not required as :R replaces permissions
# replace all permissions, give full control to currently logged in user
icacls.exe $path /GRANT:R "$($env:USERNAME):(F)"
# Remove all inheritances
icacls.exe $path /inheritance:r
```

Answer (score 2):

If we are still looking the solution of the SSH problem:

1. Go to your private key and add the root user (make sure you are adding the owner of the computer) of your computer and provide full rights.
2. Remove the other users.

If we are not able to remove the users:

1. Go to the security tab in Properties tab and click on Advanced
2. In next screen there will be a Disable Inheritance button - click on that.
3. It will open a popup and select the first option (Convert inherited permissions..) and then try removing.

In my issue, I was trying to connect ec2.prem file which is a private key to AWS and after following above steps, I was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same error on windows, but after moving the private key file to "C:\Users\Administrator.ssh" it works fine
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing permission but that didn't work.
What worked for me was changing the ownership to current user, as the key was created by other Admin user

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you have to follow the below list of steps to remove the error you are facing.

Steps:

1. Right click on the file and go to properties and select the security tab.
2. Then click on the advance button located the below right corner.
3. In new window of "Advance Security Settings For "Your File Name shown" click on the "Disable Inheritance" and remove all the Inheritance.
4. Click Apply and Ok and go delete the all users listing in the security tab window by click on the "Edit" button.
5. Once removed all users then click on "Add" button. Then type the username you using for you windows screen.
6. Allow the all permission for user name you added. and click on apply and ok.
7. Execute the same command again to login using the ssh then you will get  successfully login to system.
8. In case same problem occurs please follow the steps 1 to 7 again and try.