# EC2: getting this error while launching a public EC2 in my own created VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, subnet

Please suggest me what is the exact problem. I am not able to understand
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You ssh keys doesn't have proper permissions. You need to update the permissions in the security context of the file by locating the file in windows explorer.

```
icacls .\private.key /inheritance:r
icacls .\private.key /grant:r "%username%":"(R)"
```

There is another SO post with the exact command [OpenSSH using private key on Windows (“Unprotected private key file” error)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48923846/2246345)

More details are here [Windows SSH: Permissions for 'private-key' are too open](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open)