# Why does windows run gitlab-runner report insufficient permissions

Tags: windows, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

```
$ ssh -i id_rsa xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx echo "hello world:w"
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "C:\\Users\\xxx\\id_rsa": bad permissions
```

Remote desktop to powershell of gitlab-runner computer, ssh can be completed, but ssh cannot be run in gitlab-runner, I want to use the command tool to fix, not the window interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSH using private key on Windows ("Unprotected private key file" error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888365/openssh-using-private-key-on-windows-unprotected-private-key-file-error)

Comment: I think I should have no permissions， gitlab-runner reports the following error```$ icacls.exe ${SSH_TOKEN_FILE} /GRANT:R "$($env:USERNAME):(R)"
DESKTOP-EFH2IK5$: �ʻ����밲ȫ��ʶ�����κ�ӳ�����ɡ�
�ѳɹ����� 0 ���ļ�; ���� 1 ���ļ�ʱʧ��
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1```